# Looking for documentation that explains when SF sends multiple records to a Trigger

Tags: trigger, bulkification, triggercontext

I've been writing trigger code for years so that it handles multiple DML events for a long time.  I've been trying to find documentation that explained when SF would bundle multiple DML events submitted via the UI.  I understand why it happens from within Apex, Data Loader, Bulk API, etc.  What I'd like to find out is the timeframe for when SF will see two record updates via the SF UI and feed them into the same Trigger call.  I keep seeing "at the same time" in everything that I've read, but does SF do this when it sees creates/updates happening within the same second?  Fraction of a second?  The exact same moment in time?

Answer (score 3):

Some examples (to add to David Reed's answer)

- Data Loader - the number of records presented to the trigger in a *single transaction* is configured in Data Loader Settings (default = 200)
- Bulk API (similar to Data Loader)
- Platform Event subscriber - Here, the events arrive to Salesforce like shoppers queueing up for the cashier - stochastically. SFDC may or may not group 1 or more events into a single transaction presented to the trigger based on the arrival rate. This transaction can be as many as 2000 records but can be configured downwards in `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` metadata
- Any arbitrary Aura/LWC controller, REST service, invocable Apex, VF controller, or frankly, any Apex class that can create a collection of sobjects and do DML on that collection; the trigger will receive the entire collection in *one transaction*, presented in batches of 200 each

But, two user screens (even the same user with two tabs open) will upon Save, create two transactions that run independently and possibly concurrently to each other.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig!  That potentially may address another issue I was researching.  I'm adding a link here in case anyone else is curious about it:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/configuring-platform-event-subscriber-config-using-metadata-devani

Comment: `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` has other uses - like changing the running user from `AutomatedProcess` to one that can send emails

Comment: So it is possible for multiple trigger invocations generated by different user contexts to be processed simultaneously within a given org instance?

Comment: Yes -- that is correct. The only time where a trigger is single-threaded is a Platform Event subscriber (that is, an after insert trigger on XXX__e will never run concurrently).

Answer (score 3):

Historically, triggers only worked on one record at a time, back in the days when the API had no bulk capability, either. Bulk capability was added sometime around API 5.0 or so, from what I remember of my research on the topic previously. The documentation doesn't list all of the actions that perform bulk insert, update, delete, etc, it would just take experience to learn the various places that these operations can occur. Consider it a limitation of the platform; the documentation is strictly organized by category (Sales, Marketing, etc), so it doesn't cover questions like "where can the UI make bulk updates?"

Here's a non-exhaustive list of places in the UI that can trigger bulk DML:

- Flows

  - Screen
  - Scheduled
  - Record-Triggered
  - Autolaunched
  - Platform Event-Triggered
- List Views

  - Add Campaign Members
  - Change Campaign Member Status
  - Inline Edit
  - Add Products (Price Books, Opportunities, Orders, Work Orders, Quotes, etc)
  - Edit Products
  - Recycle Bin (Undelete)
- Import Wizards

  - Campaign Members
  - Accounts
  - Contacts
  - Custom Objects
- Reports

  - Add to Campaign

This list includes only the features that involve low/no code. Once you get into Apex, Visualforce, Lightning Components, API, etc, there could be many DML operations firing in a single transaction or even multiple transactions.

However, note that every transaction is isolated from each other. Two or more users making an update "at the same time", or one user making updates even at the same literal millisecond, won't cause trigger bulkification. It's only when a user performs an action that submits multiple records at once that a trigger will see more than one record at once.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying to find documentation that explained when SF would bundle multiple transactions submitted via the UI. [...] What I'd like to find out is the timeframe for when SF will see two record updates via the SF UI and feed them into the same Trigger call

It doesn't. There are a couple of key misconceptions in this question.

Firstly, trigger code doesn't handle multiple transactions. It may process multiple *DML events* in the same transaction (such as an `insert` followed by an `update`), or multiple batches of records for the same event in the same transaction (such as 2 batches of 200 Accounts followed by one batch of 150 Accounts). But it never handles multiple transactions. That wouldn't be meaningful: the transaction is the scope for your limits, your static variables (that is, your trigger's ability to hold state), and the units of change that get committed to the Salesforce database.

> What I'd like to find out is the timeframe for when SF will see two record updates via the SF UI and feed them into the same Trigger call

Salesforce does not do this as such.

Now, the *UI implementation* may collect and batch user-initiated actions and submit them to the underlying API and DML layers as a group, in which case they go through in a single transaction. That would apply only to a single user's interaction with multiple records in the same UI context. And resuming Flow interviews and time-based workflow rules are batched.

But multiple DML operations that occur at the API or UI layer in disparate contexts? No, the platform does not coalesce these actions. They take place in separate transactions.

---

Edit: let's look at an example.

If I run this Apex code:

```java
Account a = ...;
Account b = ...;

insert a;
insert b;
```

that is one transaction containing two DML operations. An `insert` Apex trigger on `Account` will be executed *twice*, with `Trigger.new` containing one item in each invocation.

If instead I did

```java
Account a = ...;
Account b = ...;
insert new List<Account>{a, b};
```

the same Apex trigger would be invoked once, with two `Account` records in `Trigger.new`. Still one transaction.

If that `List<Account>` contains 300 records, my trigger will be invoked twice: once with 200 records, and once with 100 records. All one transaction, all one source user.

Now, if I go to the API and I perform exactly the same DML operations via the [sObject Rows Create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) endpoint, and my friend does exactly the same thing at exactly the same time, the behavior *does not change*. It is irrelevant how many people hit

> POST https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Account/

at the same time. Every one of those operations is a separate transaction, each (in this example) containing one DML operation.

The platform *never* coalesces (and *cannot* coalesce) DML operations between users into a single transaction.

Comment: I posted this late in the afternoon (for me) and mixed up some of my terminology.  So, apologies there.  However, I don't understand your last statement.  If I submit via Apex three record updates for the same object, they are bundled and sent to the Apex trigger at the same time.  They are all in the same context.

Comment: Are you saying that if two users submit a DML update on records for the same object at the exact same time, SF won't send them both to a single Trigger invocation?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just not true, in both cases. I've edited my answer above to provide some additional specifics.

Comment: Got it.  This helps tremendously!  I've never had to deal with high-volume SF applications before, so this was a blind spot for me.  The customer I'm currently supporting may want something a bit more official than Stack Exchange to alleviate concerns.  Is this behavior described in any SF documentation anywhere?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative - I am not aware of any documentation that explicitly states that DML actions are not coalesced across user contexts. I would try to educate this customer on the principles of how platform transactions and user contexts work, which should make clear that such coalescing would not make sense.

Comment: Honestly I never thought about this topic before.  The project I'm on now is the first high-volume one I've ever worked on.  I get your point but its not about proving a negative, its communicating to SF clients (and developers) how the platform works.  SF documents everything to the nth degree, a fact that I appreciate and tout about the platform.  Would take them little to no time to write a paragraph or two on this topic.